# PHP list arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to list arrays from an array with function?

I have configuration array of a plugin in which I wast to call function which will list arrays from array.

```
'fields' => array(
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something')
            )
```

**I made function:**

```
function config(){
                $a = array('id'=>'someidA','id'=>'somethingA');
                $b = array('id'=>'someidB','id'=>'somethingB');
    return array($a,$b);

}
```

**When call config() function in array I get:**

```
'fields' => array(
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array(
                      array('id'=>'someidA','id'=>'somethingA'),
                      array('id'=>'someidB','id'=>'somethingB')
                      )
            )
```

**But I need:**

```
'fields' => array(
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                array('id'=>'someidA','id'=>'somethingA'),
                array('id'=>'someidB','id'=>'somethingB')
            )
```

I know this works:

```
'fields' => array(
                    array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                    array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                    array('id'=>'someid','id'=>'something'),
                    list($a,$b)=config(),
                    $a,$b,
                )
```

But it does not help me too much, as sometime there are lot of $a,$,$c,$d etc, so it will be the best if somehow function could list those arrays.

Is there some ways to get rid of that container array and list arrays directly to another array?

Comment: `array_push($fields_array,$a);` that much you need to do in your function. Means pass array to the function and inside function push that array to your original `fields` array.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` will work for you. It merges 2 or more arrays into a single array.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'fields' => array(
        array('id1'=>'someid','id2'=>'something'),
        array('id1'=>'someid','id2'=>'something'),
        array('id1'=>'someid','id2'=>'something')
        )
       );

function config(){
    $a = array('id1'=>'someidA','id2'=>'somethingA');
    $b = array('id1'=>'someidB','id2'=>'somethingB');
    return array($a,$b);

}

$config_arr = config();
$arr['fields'] = array_merge($arr['fields'], $config_arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

[Working Example.](https://eval.in/531254)

> OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => someid
                    [id2] => something
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => someid
                    [id2] => something
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => someid
                    [id2] => something
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => someidA
                    [id2] => somethingA
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => someidB
                    [id2] => somethingB
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Samir's solution...

By using the "splat operator" (`...`) to unpack the returned array from `config()` and then `array_push()` to append both subarrays, you can achieve the desired result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/barcp))

```
$config = [
    'fields' => [
        ['id1' => 'someid', 'id2' => 'something'],
        ['id1' => 'someid', 'id2' => 'something'],
        ['id1' => 'someid', 'id2' => 'something']
    ]
];

function config() {
    $a = ['id1' => 'someidA','id2' => 'somethingA'];
    $b = ['id1' => 'someidB','id2' => 'somethingB'];
    return [$a, $b];
}

array_push($config['fields'], ...config());
var_export($config);
```